# Is it possible to save an object in Django by iterating over self._meta.get_fields()?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-orm

I am trying to dynamically acquire my Django Models using apps.get_model(), and then call a method from said Model to properly save the data I am passing it.

```
temp_model = apps.get_model(app_label='app', model_name=model)()
temp_model.save_data(data)
```

So far, I am able to access the Model's that I am working with, as well as the method within each Object. What I am unsure of is how to properly save the data within the Object. I have been attempting to use self._meta.get_fields() to iterate over each field and set the field equal to the data I am passing it, but this is where I am getting caught up.

Here is how I am accessing a list of the Model's fields. This is working as expected.

```
def save_data(self, data):
    fields = [field for field in self._meta.get_fields() if field.name not in ['id', ]]
```

What I am unsure of is how I can then set the fields data to the appropriate piece of data that I want to pass it, and then save the Object.

Comment: Why don't you use a ModelForm?

Comment: I'm not familiar @DanielRoseman. I'm reading through the documentation and see the potential. Do you mind going a bit more in-depth? I'm also unsure of how to acquire the ModelForm like I am the Model using  ```apps.get_model()```.